# Extract value from an array of array in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I have a form and I serialised it to send it to PHP (AJAX) :

```
var dataString = $('#form_filtre').serializeArray();
```

I would like to extract **in PHP** value where names is "ou" :

```
    array(1) {
  ["form_serialize"]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(3) "ctr"
      ["value"]=>
      string(6) "maison"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(6) "action"
      ["value"]=>
      string(17) "readHomesLocation"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(2) "ou"
      ["value"]=>
      string(1) "8"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(2) "ou"
      ["value"]=>
      string(1) "6"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(5) "quand"
      ["value"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    [5]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(3) "max"
      ["value"]=>
      string(3) "500"
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to extrat 6 and 8.

The problem, is that I don't know in advance how many "ou" I will have.

It can be from 0 to n

Comment: not hard to research how to filter an array or iterate array and use conditionals to do what is needed. Not clear what you plan to do with this data

Comment: the target is to use the value of "ou" in a sql request.

Comment: That doesn't explain much but going back to first statement you can use php array filtering or simply iterate array and check that value and react accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like an easy approach would be to have PHP unserialize the array, then iterate over it with a foreach loop like this:

```
foreach($array as $index => $subArray) {
    foreach($subArray as $key => $val) {
        if ($key == "ou") {
            $ouArray[$index] = $val;
        }
    }
}
```

(where $array, obviously, is your unserialized array)

You could also just use `$ouArray[] = $val`, if you don't care which element the ou belonged to.